# Recursively setting hash keys from an array of keys

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-hash

I want a function that can take an array like `[:a, :b, :c]` and recursively set hash keys, creating what it needs as it goes.

```
hash = {}

hash_setter(hash, [:a, :b, :c], 'value') 
hash #=> {:a => {:b => {:c => 'value' } } }

hash_setter(hash, [:a, :b, :h], 'value2') 
hash #=> {:a => {:b => {:c => 'value', :h => 'value2' } } }
```

I'm aware that Ruby 2.3's `dig` can be used for *getting* in this way, though that doesnt quite get you to an answer.  If there was a setter equivalent of dig that'd be what I'm looking for.

Comment: Why would you ever want this? o.0'

Comment: I'm mapping parent -> child relationships from an array to a hash.

Comment: What's the first parameter meant to do? I don't really understand what your aim is

Comment: @Alexander the first parameter is the hash you're modifying.

Comment: You never said anything about "modifying". You need need to clarify what you want.

Comment: Hopefully edit with modification clarifies

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142992/discussion-between-alexander-and-babonk).

Comment: *'Looking for the shortest, most elegant answer"* - opinion-based question. *"built-in or one-liner"* – sorry, i wouldn't ordinarily comment on this stuff, but you've triggered me 4 times in 2 sentences...

Comment: @naomik By those standards, this should be on codegolf.stackexchange.com

Comment: Removed the offending lines

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
def nested_hash(keys, v, h={})
  return subhash(keys, v) if h.empty?
  return h.merge(subhash(keys, v)) if keys.size == 1
  keys[0..-2].reduce(h) { |g,k| g[k] }.update(keys[-1]=>v)
  h
end

def subhash(keys, v)
  *first_keys, last_key = keys
  h = { last_key=>v }
  return h if first_keys.empty?
  first_keys.reverse_each.reduce(h) { |g,k| g = { k=>g } }
end
```

**Examples**

```
h = nested_hash([:a, :b, :c], 14)    #=> {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>14}}}
i = nested_hash([:a, :b, :d], 25, h) #=> {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>14, :d=>25}}}
j = nested_hash([:a, :b, :d], 99, i) #=> {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>14, :d=>99}}}
k = nested_hash([:a, :e], 104, j)    #=> {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>14, :d=>99}, :e=>104}}
    nested_hash([:f], 222, k)        #=> {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>14, :d=>99}, :e=>104}, :f=>222}
```

Observe that the value of `:d` is overridden in the calculation of `j`. Also note that:

```
subhash([:a, :b, :c], 12)
  #=> {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>12}}}
```

This mutates the hash `h`. If that is not desired one could insert the line

```
  f = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(h))
```

after the line `return subhash(keys, v) if h.empty?` and change subsequent references to `h` to `f`.  Methods from the [Marshal](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Marshal.html) module can be used to create a *deep copy* of a hash so the original hash is not be mutated.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with recursion:

```
def hash_setter(hash, key_arr, val)
  key = key_arr.shift
  hash[key] = {} unless hash[key].is_a?(Hash)
  key_arr.length > 0 ? hash_setter(hash[key], key_arr, val) : hash[key] = val
end
```

Answer (score -2):

```
def set_value_for_keypath(initial, keypath, value)
    temp = initial

    for key in keypath.first(keypath.count - 1)
        temp = (temp[key] ||= {})
    end

    temp[keypath.last] = value

    return initial
end

initial = {:a => {:b => {:c => 'value' } } }

set_value_for_keypath(initial, [:a, :b, :h], 'value2')

initial
```

Or if you prefer something more unreadable:

```
def set_value_for_keypath(initial, keypath, value)
    keypath.first(keypath.count - 1).reduce(initial) { |hash, key| hash[key] ||= {} }[keypath.last] = value
end
```